# Get image URL instead of content from google drive api

Tags: php, html, node.js, google-drive-api

Trying to get image URL instead of file content from Google Drive API.
In the new version this GOOD thing is deprecated.

I searched a lot, on Google developer class there is a method, but its missing in the new version as well.

The problem is that I'm going to get lot of images from the Drive, but don't want to loose the speed of Google trying to path trough my app all images. And this is stupid also.

Is there a way to get those link somehow still?

This is my code I use to get file content:

```
$this->client = new \Google_Client();
$this->client->setAuthConfigFile('config.json');
$this->client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');


if (isset($_GET['code'])) $code = $_GET['code'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
    if (!isset( $code )){
        $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
        $filtered_url = filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        return redirect($filtered_url);
    }else{
        $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();
        // return redirect('/');
    }
}

$this->service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
$file_id = '0B3vR4cBcxn4oNm9TSlBzcngyMzQ';
$results = $this->service->files->get($file_id, array('alt' => 'media'));

$imaga = $results->getBody()->getContents();

$imageData = base64_encode($imaga);
$contentType = $results->getHeader("content-type");

$src = 'data: '.$contentType[0].';base64,'.$imageData;
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now, I think there's 2 ways you can access your Drive images with the API. That's using `webContentLink` if you want to download the file and the `webViewLink` if you want to display the file. Those are the available drive [metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) you can use.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on the same problem using **node.js** and npm package [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) (official package from google).

**The following solution is not in PHP but concept should remain the same.**

Although I'm late but it might help somebody else looking for a similar problem.

**Node.js**

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

//setup your oauth credentials and tokens

oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

var drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v2',
    auth: oauth2Client
});

drive.files.get({
    fileId: fileId, //id of the file you are looking for
    alt: 'media'
}, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    encoding: null
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

        //handle the error
    } else {
        var imageType = response.headers['content-type'];
        var base64 = new Buffer(response.data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
        var dataURI = 'data:' + imageType + ';base64,' + base64;

        res.send(dataURI);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="dataURI_received_from_above_HTTP_request"></img>
```